# How to save something via method in list Java

Tags: java, list, vector, methods, save

Hi i am trying to save arrays in a list. I want it to work in a method.

First of all my code:

```
public class TippSpeicher {
Tipp t = new Tipp();
Lottospiel spiel = new Lottospiel();

List<int[]> tipspeicher = new Vector<int[]>();

public void tippsabspeichern(){
    tipspeicher.add(spiel.getTipp());
    int[] feld = tipspeicher.get(0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(feld));
}
```

So after i used the method `tippsabspeicher` i expected that the list `tipspeicher` consists the value from the method `tippsabspeichern`.

But it does not.

My problem is that i want to include multiple methods in this class that need access to the entries in the list.

How can i put sth in?

Answer (score 0):

`spiel.getTipp()` is not adding anything into `tipspeicher`.Thats why you dont get anything printed.Rest looks fine.

Try this

```
public void tippsabspeichern(){
    int[] test={1,2,3};
    tipspeicher.add(test);
    int[] feld = tipspeicher.get(0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(feld));
}
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: spiel.getTipp() is actually a method returning a int[]; (Sorry you can't see that)

I can see that it works because in the end when i say System.out.println. it actually prints out that array that has been added by getTipp(). but when i try the following:

  public int[] tippAbrufen(){
  return tipspeicher.get(0);
  
 }

it does not work.